# Show that the differential operator is an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of real polynomials having degree at most 3, and let $L:V\to V$ be the map defined by $L(f)=f'$.

(a) Prove that $L$ is an endomorphism of $V$.

Edit: **Proof:** Obviously $L$ maps $V$ to itself. So what is left to show is it's homomorphism. So
$$ L(f+g)=(f+g)'=f'+g'=L(f)+L(g)$$
Hence $L$ is an endomorphism.

Correct?

(b) Find the rank, nullity, trace and the determinant of $L$.

Let $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ be the basis of $V$. Then

\begin{gather*}
L(1)=0 \\
L(x)=1 \\
L(x^2)=2x \\
L(x^3)=3x^2
\end{gather*}

So the matrix representation is
$$ L = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

We can see that

- Edit: $\text{Im}(L)=\text{span}\{(1,0,0,0), (0,2,0,0), (0,0,3,0)\}$. i.e. rank = 3
- Edit: Nullity = 1 b/c $4=\text{dim(L)}=\text{rank}(L) + \text{null}(L)$
- $\text{trace}(L) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^4 \ell_{ii} =0$
- $\det(L)=0$.

Correct?

Comment: For (a), why don’t you start with the definition of an endomorphism. What don’t you understand? For (b), the equations you wrote for the image and kernel are not correct (as a set, the image certainly has more than three things in it; you’re missing the word “span”…; the kernel is not trivial), but you got their dimensions right.

Comment: @symplectomorphic The dimensions are not correct with respect to the problem stated, where V is a space of polynomials with degree at most 2

Comment: @JJ Hoo: Oops yes sorry, of course you’re right. I assumed the basis was right… perhaps OP made a typo.

Comment: Yes it was a typo. I'm going to fix the 2 to 3 right now

Comment: @symplectomorphic I have updated my post with the corrections you stated

Comment: Your corrections are indeed correct! What you have provided is a proper proof showing that $L$ is indeed an endomorphism.

Comment: @JJHoo Thank you! Would you mind checking my corrections for (b) are also correct?

Comment: They are indeed! Apologies for the poor wording in my above comment, I meant to say that your corrections for both parts (a) and (b) indeed make your solutions correct! |

While the answers are correct, it might be wise to perhaps show why the image is the span of the 3 sets you provide. (It is not too hard, but should be stated anyway for the sake of proper proof-writing, even if it requires simply stating that the matrix is already of a certain form that allows us to extract columns)

Comment: It's okay! Thank you for your help!

Comment: You still need to show $L(af) = aL(f)$ in part (a), since this is part of being a linear map

Answer (score 1):

For Part (a):

Recall the definition of an endomorphism. Loosely speaking, an endomorphism is a homomorphism from a mathematical object to itself. L maps V to V, so it remains to be shown that L is a homomorphism. Is this true? (Recall the definition of a homomorphism here).

In general, when we set out to show that something follows a certain definition in mathematics, you need to prove it by writing out the definition

Your Part (b) is incorrect, as the problem states that $V$ is a vector space of real polynomials with degree at most 2. $x^3$ does not have a degree of at most 2. Your formula for calculating trace and determinants seem correct.

It should also be noted that the nullity is equal to the dimension of the null space Null(L). This is not equivalent to a kernel. The two concepts are related but are not the exact same thing.

Comment: Minor nitpick, in the first paragraph an endomorphism in this context is a homomorphism from a vector space to itself, "set" is insufficient structure.

Comment: You are, of course, correct, thank you for the correction!